# For loop SQLite SELECT statement

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop, select

Is this possible?

```
booking_details = []
for_quicksort = [1, 5, 9, 11, 19]


for i in range(len(for_quicksort)):
    fetch_booking_details = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE customer_id=?", (for_quicksort(i)))
    booking_details.append(fetch_booking_details)
```

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop, you can fetch all the details in one query:

```py
for_quicksort = [1, 5, 9, 11, 19]


for i in range(len(for_quicksort)):
    fetch_booking_details = cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE customer_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (for_quicksort,)
    )
    booking_details = fetch_booking_details.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```py
> for_quicksort(i)
> ```

You're just using the wrong type of brackets, as far as I can tell. To index a list, use square brackets `[]`. Round brackets `()` are used to call a function (and for enclosing data in some data structures, like tuples).

Corrected:

```py
for_quicksort[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list (for_quicksort). No need for explicit indexing.

```
booking_details = []
for_quicksort = [1, 5, 9, 11, 19]


for cust_id in for_quicksort:
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE customer_id=%s", [cust_id])
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        booking_details.append(row)
```